# Not a music rebus

Tags: mathematics, rebus, calculation-puzzle

What is the 6-letter word that associates with this rebus?
[image]

Helpness Meter 1:

> Figure out what the number means first.

Helpness Meter 2:

> [image]

Helpness Meter 3:

> We are going to Europe

Comment: Usually, hints are posted after some time when no one could solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 4):

The 6-letter word is

> Second

because

> The number (see hint #1) is 1/60, and the 1/2 note is alternatively called *minim*. A minim is also a fluid unit (about 59 mm³, i.e. essentially a drop - see hint #2), and it's usually abbreviated as **min**. 1/60 of a *minute* (which is also abbreviated **min**) is called "second".

As for the title,

> not only the word "minim" is used here in its non-musical meaning, but also "second" can be a music term too (an interval between e.g. C and D). But in the answer, it only means "a time unit".

Comment: You were so close...

Comment: It's very possible the intended answer is just rot13(zvahgr); this potentially fits better with the title, as it is not as commonly used as a musical term as your answer

Comment: What about the Europe hint?

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget I believe it fits too, since rot13(zvavz vf Oevgvfu (Rhebcrna) qrfvtangvba bs na 1/2 abgr, juvyr va Nzrevpn vg'f pnyyrq whfg "unys abgr").

Comment: @trolley813V However, rot13(qba'g guvax Oevgnva nccyvrf urer orpnhfr Oerkvg? (Guvf jnf boivbhfyl zrnag nf n wbxr, fbeel))